# What function does the context evaluation

Tags: perl

I know that, without an explicit `return`, the most recently evaluated expression is returned, but it is not clear to me how it applies in this code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub f1 {
    return "test 1\n";
}

sub f2 {
    f1();
}

sub f3 {
    f2();
}

my $r = f3();

print $r; # prints "test 1"
```

In this case the returned value came from an inner second-level call. I'm looking for a reference explaining the rule about this point. How to figure out what function does the context evaluation?

Comment: What do you mean by "context evaluation"?

Comment: The fact to know what value to be returned, i'm not sure about the term to use

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> the last "expression" is evaluated and returned

That is all there is to it.

`$r` is assigned the result of evaluating `f3()`.

The sub `f3` has no return statement, so it returns the result of evaluating the last statement, which is `f2()`.

The sub `f2` has no return statement, so it returns the result of evaluating the last statement, which is `f1()`.

`f1` does have an explicit return statement, so it returns that string.

Comment: In real production code, how to determine which function is responsible for the last "evaluation" ?

Comment: @AliSAIDOMAR I don't understand this question. You determine things about the code by looking at the code. How does using / not using `return` affect this?

Comment: I wondering, if a way to know from what function the last statement came from :)

Comment: @Ali SAID OMAR, Code (incl statements) usually comes from programmers, but it could also be machine-generated. There's no general way to tell which. /// But I think you mean the value returned by a sub. The value returned by a sub came from that sub (by definition). To see how that sub constructed the value, you need to look at the source code for that sub.

Comment: *"it returns the result of evaluating the last statement"*. That's wrong. The value of the last statement is returned *only if it is an expression*, otherwise the value returned is unspecified. [The documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#DESCRIPTION) is very clear on this.

Comment: @AliSAIDOMAR: *"I wondering, if a way to know from what function the last statement came from"*. You need to explain your situation better. You have provided an over-simplified example where the origin is obvious. Are you having problems debugging your programs, or do you want to write code that can tell at run time where a value was passed from?

Comment: I asked this because i'm working on legacy code doing modification on unittest. 

The existing test does assert on the returned value of (simplified exemple) f3,

Comment: @AliSAIDOMAR so you ran into problems because the code does not have explicit return statements and you don't know if the return value of something is on purpose? Bad luck. ;-) again, you start by the outside sun, check the last line and move up until you hit an expression. Note that it could be inside a block, like an else.

Comment: @AliSAIDOMAR _In real production code, how to determine which function is responsible for the last "evaluation" ?_ It is difficult. That's why PBP (Perl Best Practice) recommends to always have a `return` statement.